# How to change tag name in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have ajax form. When user submits the form javascript have to wait for response. So i want to change `button` into `p` tag. Does anybody know how to change tag name in javascript or jquery?

```
<form action="addcomment.php"  class="ajaxform" >
     <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" id="comment" >
     <button>Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't do that. You can remove (or hide) the button and add (or show) a paragraph, but you cannot transform a DOM element node from one type to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.replaceWith`.

```
$( "button" ).one( "click",function() {

    $(this).replaceWith('<p>' + $(this).html() +'</p>')

})
```

```js
$( "button" ).one( "click",function() {

    $(this).replaceWith('<p>' + $(this).html() +'</p>')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="addcomment.php"  class="ajaxform" >
     <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" id="comment" >
     <button>Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "changing" tags, you should consider to have all the tags to want already created, and then change their visibility.

HTML:

```
<form action="addcomment.php"  class="ajaxform" >
     <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" id="comment" >
     <button>Add Comment</button>
     <p style="display: none;">Loading ...</p>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        // hide <button> and show <p>
        $("button").hide();
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Append the text paragraph to the parent of the button, then remove the button itself.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().append($("<p>Loading Text</p>"));
  $(this).remove();
  $.ajax({ ... });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just disable button to prevent multiple click while ajax process:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  var obj = $(this);
  obj.attr("disabled","disabled");
  $.ajax({ 
         ... 
       success: function() {
         obj.removeAttr("disabled");
       }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Adding **disabled** classes does not work!

Comment: @IlyasDattoo `disabled` is not a class.

Comment: disabled is not class..its a attribute

Comment: But in bootstrap we have to add **disabled** class

Comment: then add class like this:  obj.addClass("disabled");

Comment: and remove class like this:  obj.removeClass("disabled");

Comment: Use `prop()` for `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Add your javascript here
$(function() {
  var form = $(".ajaxform");
  form.submit(function(event) {

    form.hide(); //hide the form 
    $("#loadingIndicator").text("loading text").show();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "addcomment.php",
      data: $(".ajaxform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
      success: function(data) {
        form.show()
        $("#loadingIndicator").hide();
      },
      error: function (error) {
            form.show();
       }
    });

    event.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

  });


});
```

```css
#loadingIndicator{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p id="loadingIndicator"></p>
<form action="addcomment.php"  class="ajaxform" >
     <input type="text" placeholder="Comment" id="comment" >
     <button>Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not valid. Becase if something goes wrong in php. The user have to refresh the page.

Comment: in the error callback you can show the form and display the errors